# Running Docker image on Jenkins -- cannot see print statements

Tags: python, docker, jenkins

I have a dockerized python script. When I run it locally with docker run, I can see the output of the python file in the command line as you would expect. But, when I run it up on Jenkins, it doesn't seem to be outputting anything in the console log.

Am I missing something? So far everything I've tried hasn't remedied the situation.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

ADD test_script.py /

CMD [ "python", "-u", "./test_script.py" ]
```

And I'm doing

```
docker build --force-rm --no-cache -t test_script -f Dockerfile .
docker run test_script
```

in my command line and on Jenkins. Jenkins runs fine, it just does not output any of my print statements. I had this issue locally, but it was remedied when I added the -u flag to the Dockerfile

Comment: Do you see any docker print statements? When I had this issue, I switched to using the python `logging`module instead of Python `print(..)`.

Comment: yeah i can see all of the docker build steps in the console. Just tried to use the logging module and it didn't work for me

Comment: @JR3652 I'm facing the same issue, did you happen to find a resolution?